# Not able to unlock cell with custom value using pd.xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe as shown in the below code. I just want to lock the header(top row) and let the user change rest of the cells. Based on the code below, it does lock the header and enable me to change the value of all the columns except for the "Date" column. I cannot change the value of date column. It should allow me to change the value of the date column too

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30],
                   'Data2': [11, 21, 31],
                   'Date': ["", 
                            "", 
                            pd.to_datetime('today')]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})
locked   = workbook.add_format({'locked': True})
worksheet.protect()
for row in range(1, 150):
    worksheet.set_row(row, None, unlocked)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

In XlsxWriter a cell format overrides a row format which overrides a column format.

The reason that the datetime cells aren't unlocked is due to the fact that Pandas applies a cell format to those cells (for the date format) and thus the row format is ignored/overridden.

The only way to avoid this would be to write (or overwrite) the date cell data separately from the other data frame data and apply an unlocked date format. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30],
                   'Data2': [11, 21, 31],
                   'Date': [pd.to_datetime('today'), 
                            pd.to_datetime('today'), 
                            pd.to_datetime('today')]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})
locked   = workbook.add_format({'locked': True})

# Write the 'Date' column data.
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 20)
unlocked_date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                            'locked': False})
worksheet.write_column('C2', df['Date'], unlocked_date_format)

worksheet.protect()
for row in range(1, 150):
    worksheet.set_row(row, None, unlocked)

writer.save()
```

Output, after modification:

[image]

Comment: But I am getting the "AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'days' error if my dataframe has nan for Date variable  ". I have updated my dataframe in the question.

Comment: If some of the column data in the dataframe is a datetime type then Pandas treats the entire column as datetime. As such the "" blank entries are converted to `NaT` which is a type that isn't supported by `write()`. In that case you should probably loop over the `df['Date']` array and write each item individually but ignore any `NaT` objects.